# assign value to dataframe in the first line meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, variable-assignment

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to add a column and set certain values based on certain conditions.

### Initialization

See my following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.arange(20),(5,4)).tolist(),columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E']=''
df.loc[0,'E']=1
df
```

Until here, everything is as wished. Output:

```
    A   B   C   D  E
0   0   1   2   3  1
1   4   5   6   7   
2   8   9  10  11   
3  12  13  14  15   
4  16  17  18  19
```

### Problem

But now, I would like to set the value of the 'E' column in the first row for which the 'B' value is larger than 8 to 3 (the same as `df.loc[2,'E']=1` but using that condition. I don't know which line it is a priori).

### Solution attempts

I have tried different things:

```
df.loc[df['B']>8,'E'].iloc[0]=3
df
```

This doesn't change any value:

```
    A   B   C   D  E
0   0   1   2   3  1
1   4   5   6   7   
2   8   9  10  11   
3  12  13  14  15   
4  16  17  18  19
```

The same holds for

```
df.loc[df['B']>8]['E'].iloc[0]=3
```

Other things I've tried result in an error. `df.loc[df['B']>8,'E']=3`works well but I  only want to assign the value in the first line meeting the condition, not in all lines.

So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.idxmax()`. Since `True` is the max of `True`/`False` it will return the index of the first `True` value for a boolean index.

```
df.loc[(df['B']>8).idxmax(),'E']=3
```

Comment: If I want assignment a value to the first three rows, there are any function?

Comment: @YANGSULIU yes, but please open a new question with your full question including a minimum reproducible example. The comments of an unrelated answer is not the place to get help.